# VScode activate conda environement automatically

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda

my VScode activates conda environment automatically. 
Why is it and How can I stop it ?

But I can deactivate it by using "conda dactivate"

Answer (score 0):

disable python.terminal.activateEnvironment